# Site Navigation Settings stop responding

Tags: error, navigation, site-settings

Me and the other interns are working away at an intranet site for our host company, and our navigation settings page has stopped working properly.
[image: Our navigation list, at time of freeze]

As soon as the items in the danger zone are selected, the page freezes completely. The only way to recover it is using IE's built in recovery tool.

Background: The last change to the page involved moving the 'Department HR' button down and hiding it.

I managed to gain temporary full control after creating a new heading outside "Current Navigation", long enough to add a heading inside it (for Applications) and placing it between the last two headings in the image. This heading now shows up on the site, but the settings page has reverted to its old state so there's a discrepancy here.

I'm clueless...

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen once and had to use PowerShell to clear out all nodes from the CurrentNavigationNodes collection and then rebuild it via the UI.  I don't have the code available for what I did but here is [a blog](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/02/14/site-settings-by-powershell-part-1-1-delete-navigation-nodes/) that has the basic instructions.  Obviously, that script will need to be customized for your specific situation and will require a server administrator fluent in both PowerShell and the SharePoint object model.